# AS3 move towards mouse click

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

In a side-scroller type game, I want the object to move wherever I click the mouse and then stop at that location. What is the best way to accomplish this? The object can only move on the x-axis so I don't have to worry about moving on the y-axis.

Comment: You get the x-location after the click, and tween the x-property of the target object to that x-location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is set a target x coordinate, then move towards it each frame (or timer tick) based on a constant movement speed.

```
const moveSpeed:Number = 5;
var targetX:Number = 0;

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, click);

function click(e:MouseEvent):void {
    targetX = mouseX;
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
}

function update(e:Event):void {
    if (Math.abs(targetX - player.x) < moveSpeed) {
        // reached target
        player.x = targetX;
    } else if (targetX > player.x) {
        // move right
        player.x += moveSpeed;
    } else {
        // move left
        player.x -= moveSpeed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use tweener:
http://hosted.zeh.com.br/tweener/docs/en-us/

And apply a tween like this:

```
Tweener.addTween(myObject, {_x:myObject.parent.mouseX, time:1, transition:"linear"});
```

And you can play with the time and the transition type. Good overview of transition types can be found here:
http://hosted.zeh.com.br/tweener/docs/en-us/misc/transitions.html